# Find the three most common words in a dictionary

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, heap

Question is to find the three most common words in a dictionary. I have come up with below code, but it does not work for some reason (I mean when I try to run it in eclipse, it directly leads me to debugging page, although I do not get any error on the compiler screen), I could not find the reason after debugging. Could you help me to find the problem?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer
>   (Unknown Source) at java.util.PriorityQueue.add
>   (Unknown Source) at generalquestions.MostCommonWords.mostCommonStringFinder
>   (MostCommonWords.java:41) at generalquestions.MostCommonWords.main
>   (MostCommonWords.java:61)

```
  public static Queue<Integer> mostCommonStringFinder (String document, int k){

    if (document == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (document.isEmpty()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Document is empty");
    }   

    String [] wordHolder = document.split(" ");     

    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    for (String s : wordHolder){

        if (!map.containsKey(s)){
            map.put(s, 1);

        }
        else{
            int value = map.get(s);
            value++;
            map.put(s, value);
        }           
    }

    Queue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < k ; i++){

        minHeap.add(map.get(i));            
    }       

    for(int j = k ; j < map.size() ; j++){

        if(map.get(j) > minHeap.peek()){
            minHeap.poll();
            minHeap.add(map.get(j));
        }
    }

    return minHeap;

}
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a helpful description of what's happening.

Comment: please provide a description of the problem and save us the time relearning what you already know! Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/).

Comment: I mean when I try to run it in eclipse, it directly leads me to debugging page although I do not get any error on the compiler screen

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(Unknown Source)
 at generalquestions.MostCommonWords.mostCommonStringFinder(MostCommonWords.java:41)
 at generalquestions.MostCommonWords.main(MostCommonWords.java:61)

Comment: I belive this is wrong  for ( int i = 0 ; i < k ; i++){
 minHeap.add(map.get(i));            
 } you put String to your map (not Integer) and you don't get all of them

Comment: You get the null pointer since map.get(0) return null and this is not allowed in PriorityQueue() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: You are looking for this map.values(); loop and add them to your minHeap

Comment: I do not get it, How can I correct it ?

Comment: What is your expected return value? The top `k` word counts?

Comment: Andreas will take care of you... have fun, both of you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` is a `HashMap<String, Integer>`, so keys are strings, i.e. words from the text.

`map.get(i)` will always return `null`, because there are no `Integer` keys in the map.

---

Since you were returning a `Queue<Integer>` I'll assume the expectation is the top `k` word counts, so replace everything from `Queue<Integer> minHeap` and on with:

```
List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
Collections.sort(counts, Collections.reverseOrder());
return counts.subList(0, k);
```

And change return type to `List<Integer>`.

*Test*

```
String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod " +
              "tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, " +
              "quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo " +
              "consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse " +
              "cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat " +
              "non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
System.out.println(mostCommonStringFinder(text, 3));
```

*Output*

```
[3, 2, 2]
```

Comment: but what this map.put(s, 1);? so the op puts one in the map ?

Comment: Yes seems correct since the key (word) is not present in the map.. then he increments

Comment: I do not get why the answer is very unclear . a little explanation does not kill anybody. @PetterFriberg I do not get your point, could you be more clear please?:)

Comment: Actually, please correct if I am wrong, when I try to map.get(s) - normally I try to reach the value of s key. why it does not work in this situation ?

Comment: It has not to do with the answer, the answer is related to the null pointer, map.put(s,1) means that for the key that is a String s, he puts value 1, so when word is repeted m.get(s) he will find 1 and increment it

Comment: `map.get(s)` works fine. No problems at all. Now, `map.get(i)` doesn't work *at all*.

Comment: Nice Andreas but if he needs the PriorityQueue, miniHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(map.values()); then poll() the numbers you need

Comment: @PetterFriberg You may be right, but the goal eludes me. Title says "three most common words in a dictionary". 1) There is no dictionary. 2) Cannot figure out how return value `Queue<Integer>` relates to desired "three words".

Comment: Thats true he probably should return the words... well its SOLVED ; )